# Least squares with a Matrix of coefficients instead of a vector.

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, least-squares

I am trying to solve a problem of the form:

minimize $ \quad f_0(X), \quad X\in\mathbb{R_{+}^{m \times n}}$

subject to $ \quad lb \leq x_{ij} \quad \forall i,j$

where:

$ f_0(X) = ||AX-B||_F, \quad A \in \mathbb{R_{+}^{k \times m}} ,B\in\mathbb{R_{+}^{k \times n}}$

$A$ and $C$ are both matrices of given values and this problem looks like a constrained least square problem except for the fact that X is a matrix instead of a vector.

Since most of the solvers accepts $f_0$ as a user defined function, I could pass $x$ as a vector and then reshape $x$ to $X$ during the evaluation of $f_0$, nevertheless I am not sure if this will invalidate the assumptions on which the solver relies (I am using a Trust-Region Constrained Algorithm). Thank you in advance for any help. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347753/minimize-a-xb-f-subject-to-xv-0?rq=1) question that is closely related to mine, but my focus is more on which solver (if any) allows to treat the problem in the current formulation instead of how to convert it to a proper constrained least squares.

Comment: Is the matrix norm here the Frobenius norm or the operator norm?

Comment: It is the Frobenius norm. I have edited the question, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Since, as you yourself observed, you can vectorize $X$, every solver that can solve the vectorization is applicable to your problem. For instance any SOCP or QP solver.